# Prepare a computer for being firstly used in my home network with a BASH script is possible?

Tags: configuration, bash-script

I need a script that detects the computer joined the same home network and standardize its folder structure. For example If there's A, B and C computers in a network which are configured to have a standard folder structure and connected to a NAS to store the downloaded files. It does not matter I downloaded a file from computer A or B or C. All newly downloaded files will be moved in some predefined special folder in the NAS. And if a 4th computer like computer D gets added to the same network, it will be configured like the 3 others in the same manner automatically by means of a script. How can I write such a script ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point I would start looking at configuration management software, such as e.g. [puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/), [cfengine](http://www.cfengine.org/) or [chef](https://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Home). These programs are built to solve that problem even in large server parks. They may be a bit of overkill when you're only using it for your home environment, but if you're interested in unix from a programming and/or sysadmin perspective, knowledge of them will be very useful for you in the long run.

Comment: Of those three, I'd say that puppet is the most complex but also most popular. Cfengine is older but may be easier to get a grip on; it also has some advantages over puppet in that it's better at editing files rather than replacing them. I've not used chef so I can't say much about it. If you have specific questions about using them, you may find some answers at [sf] - that's the sysadmin portion of the site and a search there should get a lot of answers.

Comment: Thank you again. I just started investigating them by puppet. Watched a video and thought that it is a bit commercial rather than a open source solution. Than jumped for chef, now watching a  video related with that. I'll also check cfengine afterwards. My aim is to have make a development environment + file server + media server + my web sites ( blogs, etc.) work in a coherant manner. A system adding and removing nodes will not affect the backspin. :) You most probably understood what I dreamed :)

Comment: I do, been there done that :-) Though I did it in the days before there were an abundance of config management software, through an unholy mix of versioning control software and shell scripts. Now that there are better solutions, I don't recommend the way I did it...